# How is the gradient of a function $f$ equal to the Frechet derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, limits

A mapping $f$ from an open set $S \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ into $\mathbb{R^m}$ is said to be differentiable at $\vec{a} \in S$ if there is an $n\times m$ matrix $L$ such that $\lim_{\vec{h} \to 0}\dfrac{|f(\vec{a}+\vec{h})-f(\vec{a})-L\cdot \vec{h}|}{|\vec{h}|}=0$.

If we look at it component wise, we get $\lim_{\vec{h} \to 0}\dfrac{|f_j(\vec{a}+\vec{h})-f_j(\vec{a})-L^j\cdot \vec{h}|}{|\vec{h}|}=0$ for $j=1,...,m$ where $L^j$ is the row of the matrix $L$. The text book I am reading then states that the components $f_j$ are differentiable at $\vec{x}=\vec{a}$ and that $\nabla f_j(\vec{a})=L^j$.

I fail to see how $\nabla f_j(\vec{a})=L^j$.

Comment: @WillJagy I should take that function and try to show that the gradient and the Frechet derivative are equal or do the limit and show that they are equal?

Comment: @WillJagy I see that this gives the result they state in the following paragraph, but I'm confused if I was expected to acquire this result from the limit definition.

Answer (score 1):

Gradient of function usually means right away that you are restricting to $m=1$ (otherwise we'd be talking about a Jacobian matrix). But even then, it's preferable to call the linearized map $L$ you found as the *differential*, *Frechet* or *total derivative* before associating it to the gradient vector. Take a look at the few paragraphs down in the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Differential_or_.28exterior.29_derivative).